# Mixed modifiers with a noun

Tags: relative-clauses, modification, attributive

Can you do that, modify a noun by mixing modifiers?

Say, something like this:

> 昨日買ったきれいな白い夫子の**帽子**

1. 昨日買った
2. きれいな
3. しろい
4. 夫子の

each is modifying 帽子.

Comment: What is 夫子?  ---

Comment: @Chocolate it means "teacher". I just wrote whatever first came to mind, it doesn't matter.

Comment: 夫子 wouldn't be understood as "teacher." I suggest you use 先生 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in  Basic Japanese
A Grammar and Workbook
By Shoko Hamano, Takae Tsujioka , p.30

> You can combine noun-modifying clauses with the other types of modiﬁers. Remember to keep the modiﬁed noun at the end of the noun phrase.
>
> 僕が作ったヘルシーな野菜のピザ
>
> [boku ga tsukutta] [herushii-na] [yasai-no] pizza
>
> “the healthy vegetable pizza that I made”

Comment: Note that alternative parsing is possible: 僕が作った could refer to the 野菜 rather than the ピザ.  Also, it isn't clear whether ヘルシーな applies to the 野菜 or the ピザ (although in this case, the meaning doesn't change much either way).

Answer (score 6):

I think you can do it but it can get tricky when chaining multiple modifiers. There’s a famous [garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence) demonstrating this ambiguity in  Japanese:

> 頭が赤い魚を食べた猫

It can be parsed in at least five different ways depending on which word or clause modifies what.
[image]

source: https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7442

Comment: Thanks. That's informative and hilarious.